# Table text size larger then normal after moving server

Tags: magento-1.9, css

I have recently moved my Magento installation to a new server and for some reason, the text in certain areas is larger then it used to be. As if the CSS is not working.

[image]

Anybody have a clue as to why this is happening?

Comment: Not sure how or why but it appears that this solved itself after re-indexed the whole site. Any explanation would be a appreciated.

Comment: My guess would be that the CSS was not reloaded properly in your browser. Maybe a proper refresh made the CSS load again.

Comment: Could very well be the case. When it comes to Magento and caching anything is possible.